# How to animate BorderThickness in WinUI?

Tags: c#, winui-3

My app uses WinUI 3, and I want to animate BorderThickness with a smooth transition from beginning to end. In WPF I can do this with this code:

```xml
<BeginStoryboard>
    <Storyboard>
        <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" From="0" To="3" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
    </Storyboard>
</BeginStoryboard>
```

I tried to use this code, but it changes meaning abruptly:

```xml
<Storyboard Duration="0:0:4">
    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
        BeginTime="0:0:0" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>0,0,0,0</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:3">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                <Thickness>5,5,5,5</Thickness>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: [ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.objectanimationusingkeyframes?view=winrt-22621#examples) *Animates the value of an Object property along a set of KeyFrames over a specified Duration.* You may need [DoubleAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation?view=winrt-22621#examples).

Comment: [DoubleAnimation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.animation.doubleanimation.from?view=winrt-22621) only Animates the value of a **Double** property but [BorderThickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.borderthickness?view=winrt-22621) is a [Thickness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.thickness?view=winrt-22621) value. It seems there is no such animation in WinUI3 like the built-in WPF `ThicknessAnimation`.

Comment: I asked an internal one who said that *WinUI’s animation capabilities are primarily targeted at animations which can run independently (off the UI thread). Animating layout properties is usually avoided since those need to run on the UI thread and with the heavy cost of running layout. Animating Thickness properties is not explicitly supported as it is not part of the standard Windows design.*

Comment: *Per that original thread, using ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames might be an option if each step in the transition is specified as a separate keyframe. But the layout involvement for each keyframe may prevent the animation from running smoothly. Also, BorderThickness is pixel snapped to avoid blurry borders, so each step will increase the border size by at least 1 pixel, which will limit how smooth the animation will be.*